# Is it possible to have Azure App Registration in one tenant and App Services in another

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Does anyone know if it's possible to create a App Registration in one tenant and then use that registration in another tenant within App Services?

Regards, Oskar

Answer (score 1):

In general yes it is. If you create an app registration, you might define the URL of the App Service in its reply URLs.
Then you can define on the App Service that it should use authentication with a given AAD tenant.

After all you can use AAD authentication anywhere, on an app hosted in AWS, the Google cloud or an on-prem server.
Of course the Authentication/Authorization feature of App Service is only available there, but that doesn't stop you from configuring authentication within your app.

Managed Identity is a feature that only works within the tenant connected to the subscription though.